# Error: multiple definition of `fprint' - while using SDL_ttf

Tags: c++11, mingw32, codelite, sdl-ttf, tdm-gcc

I have a custom library that utilises this code (https://www.dropbox.com/s/iwft7snjmntf160/SoASpriteFont.zip?dl=0).
The linked code was written for Visual Studio; I am using CodeLite on Windows.

Its has a SpriteFont.cpp that uses `fprintf`.

The static library that has SpriteFont as part of it compiles fine on its own and produces a `*.a` quite happily.

However when I use SpriteFont via other code, I get a linker error (if I am not mistaken):

```
D:/Coding/TDM-GCC-32/bin/g++.exe -o ./Debug/tmp @"tmp.txt" -L. -L../deps/lib/ -L../bengine/lib/  -lbengine -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lopengl32 -lglew32
D:/Coding/TDM-GCC-32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../libmsvcrt.a(dsnos00619.o):(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `fprintf'
../bengine/lib//libbengine.a(SpriteFont.cpp.o):D:/Coding/TDM-GCC-32/include/stdio.h:243: first defined here
```

I have read all over and found some similar situations but nothing that I have managed to use to resolve this.

It sounds like there is an issue with the way TDM-GCC redefines `fprint` in its' `stdio.h`, but I can't see how. Upon further examination, I believe the problem may lie with [SDL_ttf](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/), which is used by SpriteFont.

Also, I have tried using other functions from `stdio.h` and they compile fine; problem only seems to be `fprintf`

I have tried to create a barebones program to illustrate [the problem](http://www.filedropper.com/test_31). Hope it helps. Hopefully the fact it is a CodeLite project won't be a source of irritation.
If I can provide more info or code please ask.

Comment: currently evading the issue by using `<iostream>` and `std:cerr <<`, etc instead - but would be great to diagnose the issue for future reference as a learning experience

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens in MinGW when linking against a `dll` file that also has file in the form of `<NAME>.dll.a` 
To fix this, just link against the dll directly (I recently encountered the same problem when build `LLDB` debugger on Windows /w MinGW, the solution was to link directly against the `dll` file and delete the `dll.a` file

Comment: I tried removing the `libSDL2_ttf.dll.a` from my lib folder. This gave numerous `undefined reference...` errors. Is CodeLite perhaps not linking correctly solely to the `.dll`? - I have `SDL2_ttf.dll` in the same folder as the compiled `exe`. I remember reading something recently about linking directly against a dll, but maybe I am confusing things (have read a lot lately, and still learning much). Thanks a lot for the help; feels like this is heading in the right direction...